# Sleep/Delay on loop in WPF

Tags: wpf, delay, thread-sleep

I try to make an easy ping pong game, and i want it to move 5px with a certain delay in a while true loop for now.

I searched for some time now and only really found the Thread.Sleep method to do it. But sadly when i run it the window is not even loading and is stuck.

I really have no clue what the problem is and hope one of you can help me there.

My code:

```
private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int b = 0;
    while(b < 100){
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Thickness m = Ball.Margin;
        double a = m.Left;
        if (a <= 532)
        {
            m.Left = a + 5;
            Ball.Margin = m;
        }   
        b++;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep blocks the UI thread. Use a DispatcherTimer instead of a loop. And don't use Margins for absolute positioning. Put the Ball element in a Canvas and set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties.

Comment: If you really need a delay in a loop, make the MainWindow1_Loaded method `async` and call `await Task.Delay(200);`

Comment: @Clemens Thanks worked for me. Second option especially as it was easiest. You could write an answer so i can accept it

Comment: IMO, DispatcherTimer is the better design. You may probably also use a DoubleAnimation to animate the Canvas.Left property from a start to an end value.